Meshcentral recorded video quality issue or need to set buffer while playing the video in the mesh video player
I have recorded the video using mesh central while connecting the another server and saved the recorded video.
While playing the recorded video the quality of the video is not good enough or it should buffer to get the video fully load and play.
I have tried to set the resolution of the screening both the width and height, but it is affecting while connecting the another server.
We have implemented the buffer concept while playing the video in the inbuild mesh central player.
Both were not worked
